# Changed cygwin home location, now the terminal can't find my .minttyrc config file

Tags: windows, bash, cygwin, mintty

I had to change the `HOME` location for Cygwin by setting it to pick up the directory I set in `/etc/passwd` (following [the solution from here](https://superuser.com/questions/585331/is-it-possible-to-have-cygwin-ignore-the-windows-home-environment-variable)). It seems to not be a problem for the majority of my configuration files. `.bashrc` and `.vimrc` are read as expected.

But it isn't picking up the configuration for my `.minttyrc` file. It loads up with the default colors. If I try to add a new setting through Windows, by right clicking on the title bar and selecting Options, it gives me an error:

```
Could not save options to '[old home directory]':
No such file or directory.
```

If I rebuild the old home directory and put the `.minttyrc` file there, it works fine. Is there some place I need to update the location for the `.minttyrc` separately?

Comment: You shouldn't have to set HOME at all. Cygwin does all the correct magic. Do you have HOME set in the Windows environment?

Comment: I don't think the solution in your link will work with recent cygwin versions. The cygwin startup code got completely rewritten. Now for example /etc/password is no longer required. See [I am unable to find the etc/passwd file in cygwin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28573763) and https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html for more info about  how to correctly change your home directory.

Comment: @DavidPostill At work, my PC has the HOME environment variable set to a folder in a network drive. When I installed Cygwin, it created a duplicate of this folder on my Desktop and wanted to use that as the HOME folder. I changed it be the `home` subdirectory of my Cygwin install. I set up the `db_home` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as you suggested, and the other configuration files are mentioned are working properly. But it still isn't looking in the right place for `.minttyrc`.

Comment: How are you starting mintty?

Comment: Try adding `-c ~/.minttyrc` to your mintty startup shortcut ie `C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -c ~/.minttyrc -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -`

Comment: `-c FILE` is Load specified config file

Comment: That sounds promising. It's been working fine on my home machine, so I'll try it out when I get back to work on Monday.

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer then ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill, I posted a [related question](http://superuser.com/questions/942908/changing-the-home-for-cygwin) because I think the problem might be as you suggested in the comments, that my home directory is not correctly being set. The home directory seemed to be set correctly, but after a restart it got messed up again. I tried setting up a fresh install of Cygwin to remove any customization I had done by setting home from `/etc/passwd`, and it could no longer find the correct home directory even when specified in the `/etc/nsswitch.conf` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The terminal can't find my .minttyrc config file

You can use the `-c file` option to specify the location of the mintty configuration file.

The easiest way to do this is to change your mintty shortcut to

```
C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -c ~/.minttyrc -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
```

Modify as appropriate for your Cygwin setup.

---

#### Further reading

```
$ mintty --help
Usage: mintty [OPTION]... [ PROGRAM [ARG]... | - ]

Start a new terminal session running the specified program or the user's shell.
If a dash is given instead of a program, invoke the shell as a login shell.

Options:
  -c, --config FILE     Load specified config file
  -e, --exec            Treat remaining arguments as the command to execute
  -h, --hold never|start|error|always  Keep window open after command finishes
  -i, --icon FILE[,IX]  Load window icon from file, optionally with index
  -l, --log FILE|-      Log output to file or stdout
  -o, --option OPT=VAL  Override config file option with given value
  -p, --position X,Y    Open window at specified coordinates
  -s, --size COLS,ROWS  Set screen size in characters
  -t, --title TITLE     Set window title (default: the invoked command)
  -u, --utmp            Create a utmp entry
  -w, --window normal|min|max|full|hide  Set initial window state
      --class CLASS     Set window class name (default: mintty)
  -H, --help            Display help and exit
  -V, --version         Print version information and exit
```

Comment: Didn't work on my work environment because of the "HOME" situation, but I tested it out at home by putting the minttyrc configuration somewhere else and updating the path specified in the shortcut. It worked as expected.